# Метка в яндекс картах не должна пропадать при клике

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, yandex-maps-api

Не могу разобраться, как сделать так, чтобы при клике на метку в яндекс картах, метка не исчезала, как [тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/), а оставалась, как [здесь](https://www.sberbank.ru/ru/about/today/oib)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Опция `hideIconOnBalloonOpen:false` в помощь, 
как-то так:

https://jsfiddle.net/ebdf6rn3/

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
      center: [54.83, 37.11],
      zoom: 5
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.907228, 31.260503], {
      // Чтобы балун и хинт открывались на метке, необходимо задать ей определенные свойства.

      balloonContentBody: "Содержимое <em>балуна</em> метки",
      hintContent: "Хинт метки"
    }, {
      hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
      balloonOffset: [3, -40]
    });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Примеры. Балун и хинт</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="balloon_and_hint.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```